# DAX - How do you create a measure to return the most recent value in a table with date/time?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How do you create a measure to return the most recent value in a table with date/time?

The data is from a live ticker using Yahoo finance API.

I want to create a card visual that displays ONLY the most recent value of the stock price.

I already know how to do this using filters for the visual, but that's not what I want to achieve.

I want to create a measure that can display the most recent value, so that I can use this measure to not only display the most recent value, but also be able to use it in a math formula, to calculate such things as Unrealized Gains/Realized Gains based on the most recent price.

Answer (score 1):

Try a measure like this:

```
_Most Recent = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE( Stocks[Company] ),
    CALCULATE(
        VALUES( Stocks[Price] ),
        FILTER(
            Stocks,
            Stocks[Date] = MAX( Stocks[Date] )
        )
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

Keep in mind that this measure will only work in the filter context where ONE COMPANY is present. For example, you can drop this measure in a matrix with companies as the axis. Each row applies a filter context of one company. But if you try to aggregate this measure at a higher filter context (say, a card), then there is no way for the measure to know how to aggregate the most recent values across multiple values. In the measure above, BLANK() will be returned in those cases.

Comment: I tried editing your code since I don't have a column for the company name and I'm running into errors. The columns for the data set is basically just 2 columns - "adjclose" and "date".

Current_Stock_Price = 

    CALCULATE(
        VALUES('Stock Value (MSFT)'[adjclose])
                 FILTER ('Stock Value (MSFT)'[Date]) = MAX( ('Stock Value (MSFT)'[Date] )

edit: the error is in the filter section - "The syntax for FILTER is incorrect."

Comment: Is it just the missing table? After FILTER( you should first mention the table then a comma then your column.